# Use syncAdapter for real time data ( small scale of data)

Tags: real-time, android-syncadapter

in order to transfer data i want to use syncAdapter. 
i read this article :
http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html.

it's been written that " *Sync adapters run asynchronously, so you should use them with the expectation that they transfer data regularly and efficiently, **but not instantaneously**. If you need to do real-time data transfer, you should do it in an AsyncTask or an IntentService.*"

my question is - assuming that my app manage a very small scale of data( stored in parse server), will the syncAdapter provide a real time data? or still wont work instantaneously?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It will still wont work in real time, because the syncadapter is managed by android and android decides when is the best moment to sync the data. If your are using ContentProvider and `notifyChange()` this has a delay to avoid syncing by every update to the local database.